# Unable to locate element in selenium chromedriver even though it exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click the `I Agree` button on [thetimes.co.uk](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/) website however an exception is raised stating that element could not be found.

Here is what I've tried:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.thetimes.co.uk/")

time.sleep(1)

# Neither one of the below worked:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div[3]/button[2]").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div > div.message.type-modal > div.message-component.message-row > button:nth-child(3)").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".message-component.message-button.no-children").click()
```

[image: Website Image]

Is there any cookie that I can send to the website to disable the popup or anyway to click on the `I Agree` button successfully?

Comment: If you hit enter when browsing, does the popup go away? If so, you can use sendkeys. It may also remember your consent if you manually click once.

Comment: Hitting enter did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have ran into a classic iframe problem, the "I agree" button is within an inner HTML document, and you need to first switch into it before you can locate that button; see code example below,

```
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.thetimes.co.uk/")

iframe = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#sp_message_iframe_216133")
btn_agree = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > div > div.message.type-modal > div.message-component.message-row > button:nth-child(3)")

iframe_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(iframe))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_element)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(btn_agree)).click()

# remember to switch back out
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```